# Cannot resize SVG icon neither using w/height or viewBox

Tags: html, svg, resize

So, i tried to change height width and viewBox of `<svg>`, but it won't work.
Only if i change parameters in `<circle>` tag i can see resize

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqapbZ

```html
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <svg class="svg-clock" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px" class="">
    <g>
    <circle style="fill:#00AFFF" cx="256" cy="256" r="256" data-original="#FF9E24" class="active-path" data-old_color="#00A8FF"/>
    <circle style="fill:#FFFFFF;" cx="256" cy="256" r="207.469" data-original="#FFFFFF" class=""/>
    <path style="fill:#181818;" d="M342.649,196.805c7.582-7.582,7.582-19.872,0-27.453c-7.582-7.582-19.872-7.582-27.453,0  l-73.605,73.605l27.453,27.453L342.649,196.805z" data-original="#181818"/>
    <path style="fill:#EE3840;" d="M244.229,250.613L135.035,359.807c-4.738,4.738-4.738,12.42,0,17.159  c2.37,2.368,5.474,3.554,8.579,3.554c3.105,0,6.211-1.185,8.579-3.554l109.194-109.194L244.229,250.613z" data-original="#EE3840"/>
    <path style="fill:#181818;" d="M171.066,143.614c-7.582-7.582-19.872-7.582-27.453,0c-7.582,7.582-7.582,19.872,0,27.453  l99.343,99.343l27.453-27.453L171.066,143.614z" data-original="#181818"/>
    <path style="fill:#524E4D;" d="M256,286.332c-16.725,0-30.332-13.607-30.332-30.332s13.607-30.332,30.332-30.332  s30.332,13.607,30.332,30.332S272.725,286.332,256,286.332z" data-original="#524E4D"/>
    <g>
     <path style="fill:#7A7674" d="M115.261,268.133H97.062c-6.701,0-12.133-5.433-12.133-12.133s5.432-12.133,12.133-12.133h18.199   c6.701,0,12.133,5.433,12.133,12.133S121.962,268.133,115.261,268.133z" data-original="#7A7674" class=""/>
     <path style="fill:#7A7674" d="M256,127.393c-6.701,0-12.133-5.433-12.133-12.133V97.062c0-6.7,5.432-12.133,12.133-12.133   c6.701,0,12.133,5.433,12.133,12.133v18.199C268.133,121.96,262.701,127.393,256,127.393z" data-original="#7A7674" class=""/>
     <path style="fill:#7A7674" d="M414.938,268.133h-18.199c-6.701,0-12.133-5.433-12.133-12.133s5.432-12.133,12.133-12.133h18.199   c6.701,0,12.133,5.433,12.133,12.133S421.639,268.133,414.938,268.133z" data-original="#7A7674" class=""/>
     <path style="fill:#7A7674" d="M256,427.071c-6.701,0-12.133-5.433-12.133-12.133v-18.199c0-6.7,5.432-12.133,12.133-12.133   c6.701,0,12.133,5.433,12.133,12.133v18.199C268.133,421.638,262.701,427.071,256,427.071z" data-original="#7A7674" class=""/>
    </g>
    </g> 
 </svg>
```

I expect to resize this svg without modifying it

Comment: Please use this instead : `<svg class="svg-clock" viewBox="0 0 512 512">` Is this what you need?

Comment: Daym, im dumb, thanks a lot, it helped!